# How to fetch exact string from a text file

Tags: batch-file

here is me requirement.

I have one text file and I need to get exact specified string from that file

```
C:>type small.txt | find "small2"

small2

small22

small20

C:>type small.txt small2

small22

small20

C:>type small.txt | find "small2" small2

small22

small20

C:\
```

Here it is giving all the words instead of only "small2"

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I got the solution

```
C:\>findstr "\<small20\>" small.txt
small20
C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo small2`

Will give you the same result